# mootools: $ not defined

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've strange error i don't understand. I'm just moving my code from jQuery over to Mootools because it's much cleaner than the jQuery mess.

Now when i use the

```
$$('div.canvas')
```

in mootools i get the correct element.

When i try

```
$(document).getElement('div.canvas')
```

it tells me that **$** is not defined. How can **$$** and all helper functions like **$lambda** etc. be defined but not **$**?

Has something changed there from **1.1 to 1.2** and the docs are not updated yet?

Comment: I'm using jQuery with the noConflict option while I am reimplementing all of the code. Changed all my previous $ refs to jQuery. Something wrong with the noConflict option maybe?

Comment: Odd... I double checked now if a $ from jQuery was left over, but no. I even included the mootools framework after jQuery that so it could overwrite the $ but didn't work.

Although when i remove all jQuery includes it works.
Seems as noConflict() doesn't keep it's promise?

Comment: updated answer for noConlflict() examples

Comment: "much cleaner than the jQuery mess" -- not trying to start a flamewar here, but how so?

Comment: jQuery may be good for quick-and-dirty JS, but if the project grows larger I find myself constantly in trouble with jQuery. I simply like Moo's object oriented approach more than jQuery's library architecture. For instance function chaining is a pleasure with Moo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as someone pointed out, when $ is defined, mootools 1.2.3+ will not take it over, it will revert to using document.id instead. this did not used to happen before that release so it largely depends on the version you are referencing. but it's certainly changed since 1.11 and it IS documented, read the announcement here http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/

to your application design this means that, if your structure is...

load jquery (no need for noconflict, does not matter)
load mootools

... it can work as follows:

```
$("#foo"); // jquery
document.id("foo"); // mootools

// or create a temporary scope for mootools things
(function($) {
    $("foo"); // mootools
})(document.id);
```

best / recent practices in mootools development require plugins and code released to reference document.id or be within such a closure to ensure compatibility. this is actually ok as unlike in jquery where $ aliases the jQuery singleton, in mootools $ is just a selector so its use will be far less spread. Hence typing document.id("selector") is not going to be that much of a drag.

Comment: although it didn't solve my problem, i award the winning post to you ;), congrats. in the end it was faster moving all code over to moo and ignore the problem for now as to resolve the conflict itself...

Answer (score 1):

Have you removed all reference to jQuery in your htmls?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using both libraries on the same page you must use [JQuery's noConflict() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

If you are still having trouble, try checking through your included JQuery files to ensure that any plugins/code use `jQuery('div.canvas')` etc instead of `$` as `$` has been released by the noConflict() function and will not run JQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

MooTools will not override the `$` function if it exists already. It checks for nullness of `$` before defining it. So I suspect the $ is still lurking somewhere.

```
if (window.$ == null) Window.implement({
    $: function(el, nc){
        return document.id(el, nc, this.document);
    }
});
```

After including jQuery and running `$.noConflict();` but before including MooTools, can you log the contents of `$` and see what is logged?

```
include jquery
$.noConflict();
console.log($); // should return undefined
include mootools
```

Comment: When i do:

jQuery.noConflict();
console.log("jQuery there?");
console.log($);
console.log(jQuery);

It says:
"jQuery there?"
undefined
function (a, b) ....

So jQuery is defined and $ not

Comment: are there other plugins on the page or just the core libraries?

Comment: there's jquery and mootools while i'm migrating to moo, and the google api loader which i use for loading gmaps with google.load('maps', '2').

And of course my own framework.js file which i triple checked for left $'s but there are none.