# $ is not defined error in mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

```
(function () {
    //alert("hi");
    var divtag = $('maindiv').get('tag');
    //var divtag=document.getElementById("maindiv");
    console.log(divtag);

    var username = new Element("input", {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "username",
        "id": "name",
        "placeholder": "Enter username here"
    });
    divtag.inject(username);
})();
```

here is the code of my js file.Please let me know where i m making mistake.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440102/mootools-not-defined) I think is a similar post.

Comment: this code is very broken and wouldn't work. even if `$('maindiv')` returns an object, `.get('tag')` will return `'DIV'` as string. In the end, you do `'DIV'.inject(usernameElement)`. remove the `.get('tag')`

Answer (score 2):

If this works:

```
(function () {

    // >>> EXPLICITLY SET $ TO document.id:
    var $ = document.id;

    // >>> THE REST OF YOUR CODE:

    //alert("hi");
    var divtag = $('maindiv').get('tag');
    //var divtag=document.getElementById("maindiv");
    console.log(divtag);

    var username = new Element("input", {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "username",
        "id": "name",
        "placeholder": "Enter username here"
    });
    divtag.inject(username);
})();
```

then the `$` alias for `document.id` is not defined, or is defined by some other library than MooTools (maybe jQuery is also included on the page?).

(Redefining the `$` as `var $ = document.id;` inside your own function is safe even if `$` is already defined to be something else and used outside of your function - the outside `$` will not be changed here.)

Another thing is this:

```
var divtag = $('maindiv').get('tag');
```

which should probably be just:

```
var divtag = $('maindiv');
```

I assume that you have the MooTools library loaded on the page - if you don't then of course nothing will work.

Posting a link to a code example on JSFiddle, JS Bin or CodePen would make it much easier to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Now it gives Error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: @ChetanBaviskar Are you sure MooTools is loaded? Can you reproduce it in an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/)?

Comment: I added this : <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-1.2-core-nc.js"></script> js in my Project. And JSFiddle wont give any error and also there is no creation of input field by this code.

Comment: I tried this on JS Bin It gives me Error: "TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: @ChetanBaviskar can you post a link to your JS Bin example? It makes little sense to discuss a JS Bin example without actually seeing it. (also try changing the `$('maindiv').get('tag');` to just `$('maindiv');` in your code)

Comment: Yes i post this link to JS Bin. And also use $('maindiv'); and $('maindiv').get('tag');  And this gives me Error: "TypeError: $ is not a function"